# Converting a UTC String to a Date object

Tags: apex, date

I have a UTC String

```
Tue, 18 Jun 2013 23:00:00 GMT
```

I wish to convert this to a apex Date object.  How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want to use the [parse()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) method.

From the documentation:

> Constructs a Datetime from the String datetime in the local time zone
>   and in the format of the user locale. The returned date is in the GMT
>   time zone. This example uses parse to create a Datetime from a date
>   passed in as a string and that is formatted for the English (United
>   States) locale. You may need to change the format of the date string
>   if you have a different locale.

```
Datetime dt = DateTime.parse(
              '10/14/2011 11:46 AM');
String myDtString = dt.format();
system.assertEquals(
    myDtString,
    '10/14/2011 11:46 AM');
```